# Prinout Extension in Yii, how to remove header, footer and anchor tags?

Tags: php, html, css, yii, printing

This is my view code

```
<?php 
$this->widget('application.extensions.print.printWidget', array(                   
               'cssFile' => 'print.css',
               'coverElement' => '#wrapper',
               'printedElement'=>'#summary',
               )
             ); 
?>
<div id="summary">

<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
'data'=>$model,
'attributes'=>array(
    'name',
    'date_created',
    'medical_treatment',
    'remarks',
),
)); ?>
<br><br>
<center>____________________________</center>
<center>Doctor's Signature</center>
</div>
```

my controller/action

```
     public function actionPrescription($id) 
{
    $this->render('printprescription', array(
    'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
    ));
}
```

I want to print only the content of div id="summary"
the extension does let me do it but it prints out the entire page first with the header and footer

I thought the coverElement could remove it but I guess not?

can anyone help?

Comment: I haven't tried the particular extension but have you add rules (in print.css) such: @media print { #header, #footer {
  display: none; } }

Comment: yes but it's still there :/

Comment: show your related controller/action and your related view

Comment: I really don't think the controller or related view has anything to do with this... I think the extension is the problem... I'm using the printout extension by the way

Answer (score 0):

Adding print media in CSS should have helped. 
You can try adding selectors for header and footer directly into extension code.

```
    echo CHtml::css("
        .printWidgetScreenCover {display: none;}
        .printWidgetPrintedElement {display: block; margin: 20px;}
        #header {display: none;}
        #footer{display: none;}
        ",
        "print"
    );
```